# Problema con el push de un Array dentro de una variable del Objeto. Se sobreescribe todos los arrays que hay en el objeto

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo el siguiente problema intento hacer un push de un array dentro de un objeto, se hace todo correctamente pero nunca se guarda bien en el objeto porque se sobre-escribe con la nueva información que introduzco.

Dejo el StackBlitz para que podáis ver mi problema:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkwzte

Muchas gracias.

Comment: cuando asignas objetos, en realidad estas asignando la referencia; y al modificarse el objeto  todos que hacen referencia a el ven el cambio, la asignacion para los objetos y arrays son inmutables

Comment: se me olvido dar la solucion, usa [Object.Assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He revisado tu código, esta bastante bien, pero te pasaba una cosa que es la siguiente:

Metias en la array el MISMO objeto, por eso eran todos iguales. Lo he solucionado de esta manera:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ObjectA } from './object1.model';
import { ObjectB } from './object2.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  objectA: ObjectA = new ObjectA('', [], '')
  objectB: ObjectB = new ObjectB(0, '', '', '');
  //he creado un contador para el nhumero de registros
  contador: number = 0;

  savePosition(objectBrellenado: ObjectB) {
    this.contador++;
    //creo un objeto NUEVO cada vez de insertar
    this.objectA.objectPositions.push(
      new ObjectB(
        this.contador,
        objectBrellenado.description, 
        objectBrellenado.debe, 
        objectBrellenado.haber)
    );
  }
}
```

Lo que he hecho es crear objetos nuevos, para que sean independientes uno del otro, de esta manera me aseguro de que son diferentes.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Muchas gracias!! soy nuevo en esto y no entiendo mucho algunos conceptos al 100%.

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes cuando haces la asignación de valores a un mismo objeto, lo que debes hacer es generar una instancia nueva del objeto cada vez que lo guardas.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ObjectA } from './object1.model';
import { ObjectB } from './object2.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  objectA: ObjectA = new ObjectA('', [], '')
  objectB: ObjectB = new ObjectB(0, '', '', '');

  savePosition( objectB: ObjectB ) {
    if (this.objectA.objectPositions.length === 0) {
      this.objectB.id = 1;
    } else {
      this.objectB.id = this.objectA.objectPositions.length + 1;
    }

    this.objectA.objectPositions.push( objectB );
    this.objectB = new ObjectB(0, '', '', '');

  }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! soy nuevito en este mundillo.. un error bastante ploff